# What does <tag/> mean in XML?

Tags: xml

I have a question about XML syntax. I know that the closing tag
looks like `</tag>`, but what does `<tag/>` mean? For example:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c/> <-- What does it mean?
  <d/>
</b>
</a>
```

How would this XML tree look like? Is `a` only going to have `b` as a child, or would `b` also have `c` and `d` as children?

Comment: `c` and `d` are *self-closing elements*, and children of `b`. `b` is a child of `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example,

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
    <d/>
  </b>
</a>
```

`<c/>` and `<d/>` are **[empty element tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-EmptyElemTag)**:

> Empty-element tags may be used for any element which has no content,
>   whether or not it is declared using the keyword **EMPTY**. [For
>   interoperability](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-interop), the empty-element tag should be used, and should
>   only be used, for elements which are declared EMPTY.

*How would this XML tree look like?*

The containment tree would be as shown above via indentation.

*Is `a` only going to have `b` as a child?*

Yes.   `b` and `c` would be **descendants**, but not children, of `a`.

*Would `b` also have `c` and `d` as children?*

`c` and `d` are children of `b` alone, not of `a`.