# New line between empty elements with etree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I added short_empty_elements=False to the write func of etree so that when I have an empty elements ,such as  <\t>, it will write it in this format:

```
<root>
  <t></t>
</root>
```

My problem is that I need it to be in seperate lines, like this:

```
<root>
  <t>
  </t>
</root>
```

and I can't figure out how to do it.

.text='\n' or .text='' both don't work.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

While `<t/>` and `<t></t>` are equivalent,

```
<t/>
```

and

```
<t>
</t>
```

are not.  The first form is an empty `t` element; the second, a `t` element that contains newline and space characters.

You will not find a serialization option to output the second form in place of the first.  You will have to update the content of `t` to be as you wish prior to serialization, or, preferably, you will have to re-evaluate you motivation for such a suspect requirement in the first place.

### See also

- [How to add a newline (line break) in XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35504890/290085)
- [Is there a semantic difference between <tag /> and <tag></tag> in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57494936/290085)
- [What does <tag/> mean in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39184716/290085)